# ng-transclude replaces the content instead of append

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS.

I went through this [video](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/78mqI0uBYF/angularjs-transclusion-basics), here it shows putting `ng-transclude` on a tag in the template of directive, will append the already present DOM stuff in this tag.

Code :

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <panel>
        <button>Click Me</button>
    </panel>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('AppCtrl', function() {

            });
            app.directive('panel', function() {        //can return a function (link) or an object
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    transclude: true,
                    template: '<span> This is my custom span</span><div class="panel" ng-transclude>this is my div</div><span>Another span follows</span>'
                }
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/PjCFH/), demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the normal behavior of the latest version.

From [Angular API on ng-transclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude).

```
"Any existing content of the element that this directive is placed on will be removed before the transcluded content is inserted."
```

If you run your fiddle with Angular version 1.0.8, then it will work like in the video.

Comment: use a transclusion function

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<span>` as the transclusion host:

```
// Assign tpl var to template configuration property
var tpl = [
        '<span> This is my custom span</span>',
        '<div class="panel">',
            '<span ng-transclude></span>',
            ' this is my div',
        '</div>',
        '<span ng-switch-when="divider"></span>',
        '<span>Another span follows</span>'', // End
    ].join('\n');
```